# Ionic select, preselected value with options loop

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

Im trying to create ion-select with preselected value and generated options but Im facing problem, initial select is not displayed until I interact with select. I assume that this component is checking for available options to display based on given value and then generating options in *ngFor loop. Am I doing it wrong? Or is there any way to solve this problem?

```
<ion-select value="preselect.id">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item.id">
       {{ item.name}}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue with adding ngModel .

```js
 <ion-select (click)="loadcurrency()" [(ngModel)]="selectedcurrency">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies" 
      value="{{currency.name}}">{{currency.capital}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

And at .ts file

```js
 selectedcurrency = "aud";

 loadcurrency() {
 ....//initialize the array for options
 }
```